# How to prevent song item to start over again after being selected?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have a collection view, that has a few songs, and upon selecting these songs, the app moves into a playerVC where the pause button is and the song image.
If the user selects song a for example, the music starts so "player.play()" is true, and then the user is moved into a playerVC with it's image etc, now say the user leaves this playerVC and wants to return to it to pause the song, the whole song restarts. How can I prevent this from happening? I know I have to implement an If statement to do something is "player.isPlaying" but do not know what to put in it.

This is the class where the audio is initialised

```
class SoundManager {
    public var position = 0
    public var songs: [Song] = []
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?    
    func playNavPlayer() {
        let song = songs[position]
        let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: song.trackName, ofType: "mp3")
        do {          
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default) ///app needs to know what mode we are working on
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            guard let urlString = urlString else { return }
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
            guard let player = player else {return}
            player.volume = 0.5
            // player.play()
            // player.delegate = self
            player.numberOfLoops = -1
        } catch {
            print ("Error")
        }
    }    
}
```

Updated Singleton Class

```
 class SoundManager {
       private init(){ } 
       static let shared = SoundManager()
       public var position = 0
       public var songs: [Song] = []
       var player: AVAudioPlayer?
       var songURL: URL!
    
       func playNavPlayer() {
           let song = songs[position]
           let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: song.trackName, ofType: "mp3")

           do {
            
           try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default) ///app needs to know what mode we are working on
           try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

            guard let urlString = urlString else { return }
        
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
        
            guard let player = player else {return}
            player.volume = 0.5
            player.play()
            //player.delegate = self
            player.numberOfLoops = -1
            
            }
         
         catch {
             print ("Error")
         }

       }
```

How this class is called

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
      
      //present player
    let position = indexPath.item

    
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "player") as? PlayerViewController else {
          return
      }
    
            func push() {
           
            vc.songs = songs
            vc.position = position
            vc.soundManager = SoundManager.shared
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)     
    }
      SoundManager.shared.songs = songs
    SoundManager.shared.position = position
    if SoundManager.shared.player?.isPlaying == true && SoundManager.shared.player?.url (This is where I need to see compare song playing with song clicked) {
        push()
    }
    else {
        SoundManager.shared.playNavPlayer()
        push()
    }
    SoundManager.shared.setupRemoteTransportControls()
    SoundManager.shared.setupNowPlaying()
    
    //songs
    
 }
```

Song Declaration

```
 
         var songs = [Song]()

         func configureSongs() {
        
          songs.append(Song(name: "Empire", imageName: "cover1", trackName: "Empire"))
          songs.append(Song(name: "FirstSample", imageName: "cover2", trackName: "FirstSample"))
          songs.append(Song(name: "TBH", imageName: "cover3", trackName: "TBH"))
          songs.append(Song(name: "Trials", imageName: "cover4", trackName: "Trials"))
          songs.append(Song(name: "Magic Spells", imageName: "cover5", trackName: "MagicSpells"))
          songs.append(Song(name: "Still Goin", imageName: "cover6", trackName: "StillGoin"))
        
     }
```

```
   Song, is a struct
```

```
     import Foundation


      struct Song {
    
         let name: String
         let imageName: String
         let trackName: String
     }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219579/discussion-on-question-by-the-vitruvian-man-how-to-prevent-song-item-to-start-ov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Song struct should conform the Equatable protocol, in order for us to use a function in which we compare two instances of our Song struct, like this

```
    struct Song: Equatable {
    
         let name: String
         let imageName: String
         let trackName: String
         static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
         return lhs.trackName == rhs.trackName
    }
     }
```

And then when we select a song(item) in didSelect we implement an if function to check wether the player is playing and also to compare the two track names, the one that is playing and the one we just clicked on, then if true we specify what we want to do in the curly brackets.

```
     
        if SoundManager.shared.player?.isPlaying == true && songs[position] == SoundManager.shared.songs[SoundManager.shared.position] {
            
            //Whatever you want to do
            
        }
```